# Generalized Lax-Milgram for Weak Formulation of 1D Linear Schrodinger

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization, finite-element-method

I am interested in the variational formulation of the 1D Schrodinger equation:

$i u_t- \beta u_{xx} = 0 $ and $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ which upon integration by parts yields:

$i(u_t,v) + \beta (u_x,v_x) = 0$ and the boundary terms vanish by appropriate testing with test functions $v$. We then have the continuous sesquilinear form $b(u,v) = i(u_t,v) + \beta (u_x,v_x)$. I would like to apply the generalized Lax-Milgram on $b(\cdot,\cdot)$, but I am having trouble showing the boundedness below (coercivity) of $b(\cdot,\cdot)$. Is there a slick way to show $b(u,u) > \alpha \|u\|_{H^1}^2$?

Comment: Do you mean space-time $H^1$ in your final inequality?

Comment: yes, I meant space-time

Comment: or even first with $L^2$ in space-time. I'm having trouble with the complex coefficient

Comment: Yes, you are right, I could not control both but I guess then I can control spatial $H^1$ and $L^2$ in time, right?

Comment: Let me be a bit less sloppy: does $H^1$ mean $$ \|u\|^2 = \int_t \int_x |u_t|^2 + |u_x|^2 + |u|^2$$ or $$ \|u\|^2 = \int_t \int_x |u_x|^2 + |u|^2$$ or something else altogether?

Comment: I initially meant the first one, but as you said, coercivity needs more, so I can settle with the second $H^1$ with no $|u_t|^2$ term. Also, when you say $(u_t,u)=0$ do you mean the complex $L^2$

Comment: Notice also that if $\int_x |u|^2$ is not constant in time, then $i (u_t,u)$ is not necessarily real valued. // To your question: what I wrote was not what I meant, hence the comment is deleted.

Comment: Ok, but if $\int_{x} |u|^2 $ is constant for all time, how does it follow that $(u_t,u) = 0$ since you would have the conjugate terms as well

Comment: I am not even convinced that your quadratic form is positive. I wonder if you have additional assumptions that you didn't tell us. Please be a lot more detailed with your set-up. For example: what is the space-time domain you are looking at? What are the boundary conditions? On $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ for example you can take $u = e^{it\theta} \sin(\pi x)$ for an appropriately chosen $\theta$ to make $b(u,u) < 0$.

Comment: it does not. What I wanted to write (which is just a scaling argument) has nothing to do with $(u_t,u)=0$.

Comment: Sorry -- I will be more specific. My domain in space time is $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{+}$ with $u(x,0)=u_0(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I have decay at infinity in the $x$ direction

Comment: I want to show that if I define the operator $B: D(B) \subset L^2(\Omega)\rightarrow (L^2(\Omega))'$ as $<Bu,v> = i(u_t,v) + \beta (u_x,v_x) $ then $B$ is bounded below.

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: $\Omega = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: possibly related : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1648621/2987

Answer (score 3):

Your method is doomed to fail. For several reasons.

1. Suppose that $u$ solves the linear Schrodinger equation. Using Fourier methods it is easy to see that $\| u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^2_x}$ is conserved and independent of $t$. This means that $u$ *cannot* be in $L^2(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_+)$. So there is zero chance that Lax-Milgram can give you any indication on how to get a solution.
2. Forgetting item 1 above. Observe that if Lax-Milgram were to work, you solution $u$ will satisfy $B(u,v) = \langle 0,v\rangle = 0$ for any $v$, since you are solving the homogeneous Schrodinger equation. This implies immediately that $B$ cannot be coercive.
3. Forgetting items 1 and 2 above, suppose $u$ is a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+)\cap C^2$, then necessarily $\liminf_{t\to\infty} \|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^2_x} = 0$. But then unless $u_0 \equiv 0$, $B(u,u)$ must have a non-vanishing imaginary part.
4. Lax-Milgram is intended to provide a weak solution to the *linear* partial differential equation $L u = f$ for $u$ belonging to some Hilbert space $H$. In the case $f = 0$ however the existence of a solution is trivial! Namely that $u = 0$ will solve the equation.

   In your problem you are prescribing a boundary value $u_0$. This is not in the usual form of Lax-Milgram. Furthermore, by fixing the boundary value $u_0$ you destroy linearity; in other words, in makes no sense to look at the functional on a Hilbert space $H$, since you cannot add two elements with boundary value $u_0$ and obtain another element with boundary value $u_0$.

Comment: I agree, but have the following fixes: I could do a weighted $L^2$ norm with a Gaussian weight $e^{-t^2/2}$ so that $\int_{x,t} e^{-t^2/2} |u|^2 =  KC_0 < \infty $ and $C_0 = ||u(\cdot,t)||_{L_{x}^2}$ is the conserved total energy. By working with a nonzero right hand side, the issues (2) and (4) regarding homogeneous $u=0$ solution are resolved.

Comment: Then for $u$ in your weighted space, $B(u,u)$ cannot possibly be coercive.  Let $v\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ be any function, normalized to have $L^2$ norm 1. Let $\lambda = \| \partial_x v\|_{L^2}$. Now take $u = \exp (i\theta t) v$. Clearly $u$ has finite weighted $L^2_{t,x}$ norm. But note that $i \bar{u}_t u = \theta |v|^2$. Take $\theta < - \lambda$ then you see that $B(u,u)$ cannot be coercive.

Comment: Perhaps this is also a good time to mention that for actual solutions to the Schrodinger equation, $\|u_x(\cdot,t)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$ (the energy) is also conserved in time. So your form $B$ is not continuous there.

Comment: One final comment, and no more from me on this topic: many evolution equations in physics can be obtained as a formal critical point of an action functional. The formal Lagrangian for the Schrodinger equation is essentially $B(u,u)$ as you had written. But it is fairly well-known that (1) for most equations of physics the formal Lagrangian does not converge (so really only the Lagrangian density is defined) due to natural conservation laws and (2) that for most equations of physics the solutions are saddle points of the functional (in the sense that the formal second variation has no sign)...

Comment: ... both of these make naive space-time variational approaches unsuitable for studying equations of physics. (In contrast, the Hamiltonian approach has much firming functional analytic footing.) The two problems both come up in your attempt to use Lax-Milgram. That for solutions to the linear homogeneous equation $B(u,u) =0$ (formally) and that it is possible to construct functions for which $B(u,u) < 0$ (formally) really is a manifestation of problem (2).